# Using OpenCV with Java after Javacv moved from google code to github repo "bytedeco"

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, face-recognition

I am working on face recognition using java and OpenCV, and the problem is Javacv became hosted by github "bytedeco" repo , so i can't import MatVector, "createFisherFaceRecognizer" and other thing although i have added bytedeco jars in my project and OpenCV is installed on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

mainly i mean simple face recognizer like this: https://pcbje.github.io/misc/2012/12/01/doing-face-recognition-with-javacv.html

the question is can i use Opencv without javacv and javacpp ? and if i can't what about javacv and javacpp hosted by bytedeco? , cause i have added all JAR's of bytedeco (javacv, javacpp and Opencv libaray) in my project).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of not clear for me but to answer "the question is can i use Opencv without javacv and javacpp ?" question yes you can use opencv for c++ only but if java is mandatory use JNI(java native interface) use the java as it is and use c++ opencv code.